# SDL 2.0 does not create contex with version 2 on some android devices

Tags: android, sdl

I have the problem. On some devices SDL 2 can not create context with version 2.

Code:

```
EGLint context_attrib_list[] = {
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,
    2,
    EGL_NONE
};

EGLContext egl_context;

egl_context = 
_this->egl_data->eglCreateContext(_this->egl_data->egl_display,
                                  _this->egl_data->egl_config,
                                  EGL_NO_CONTEXT, context_attrib_list);
```

eglCreateContext return EGL_NO_CONTEXT. But if I set EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION as 1 eglCreateContext successfully create context.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: With SDL2 on Android, OpenGL ES contexts are created with SDL_GL_CreateContext. What you posted makes no sense in the context of SDL.

Comment: Well, if you can, please, describe me why this code work excellent on Smsung Gelaxy S3 and does not work on Nexus?

Comment: The same problem: sometimes SDL_GL_CreateContext raises with "Could not create EGL context" on Kindle Fire or Galaxy Nexus (the same video unit?), but not on Galaxy S3 and other.